# Display Validates Error Messages in View using form_tag  - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i want display this errors when my model dont validate

Model:

```
  validates_length_of  :name ,:minimum => 6,:on => :create
  validates_length_of :password ,:minimum => 6,:on => :create
```

but in my view this dont appear my view is

```
<h1>Cadastro</h1>
    <% if flash[:note] %>
    <%= flash[:note] %>
    <%end%>
    <%= error_messages_for :user %>
    <% for erro in @user.errors.full_messages %>
    <%= erro %>
    <% end %>
<%= form_tag users_path do %> 

     <%= label_tag :name %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :name,params[:name] %><br />
  <%= label_tag :password %><br />
   <%= password_field_tag :password,params[:password] %>
<%= submit_tag "Cadastrar" %>
<%end%>
```

and my controller if need this

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end
  def create
        @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
     if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:name],params[:password])
          session[:user_id] = @user.id
          session[:user_name] = @user.name
          flash[:note] = 'Voce esta logado.'
          redirect_to finances_url
     else
       flash[:note] = 'Falha no login.'
       render 'new'
     end
  end
```

Thanks for the help i thanks very mutch

Comment: Waht model is that? Is it user or session? If that is a user, than it will be only validated on user creation, not on login. In your controller there is no creation of any model, no wonder this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks i solve this how you talk , valid in the create. Thanks very mutch.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks i solve validing and appear in the user_create whit this code:

```
<% for erro in @user.errors.full_messages %>
    <%= erro %>
    <% end %>
```